# to create logging at the time of start and down time of the spring MVC application

Tags: spring, logging, error-logging

I need to create logging (logging and entry in a DB table), with the cause or exception occurred if a running spring application is stopped abrubtly or due to any server exception occurred. Is there any concept or module in spring which I can use for this purpose?

Please help if anyone knows or have done the same thing, thanks in advance!!

Comment: If the application is killed there is no garantueed way of writing something to the db.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement EventListener for ApplicationContextStoppedEvent and there you can add your logic

Comment: Which will only work for a controlled shutdown. Not for abrubt shutdown of the application (killing the proces, machine goes down etc).